# Prove the Galois group of the splitting field of $x^4-4x+2$ is $S_4$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I aim to show that the roots of $x^4-4x+2$ is not constructible by ruler and compass. Which is left to prove is that the splitting field is exactly $S_4$. But I have no idea to prove it so far… May I please ask some possible method to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Please follow Milne's Field and Galois theory notes and look at example 4.9 .

Answer (score 4):

Factor modulo $p$ for various primes. If the group really is $S_4$
your polynomial $f$ will factor modulo $p$ in all possible ways. If you
find a $p_1$ with $f$ irreducible modulo $p_1$ and a $p_2$
with $f$ having an irreducible cubic factor modulo $p_2$, then
the Galois group will have elements of cycle structures $(4)$ and $(3\,1)$.
The only possibility will then be $S_4$.

Comment: simply finding a $p$ where $p$ has a single root (for example $p=5$) is enough to show the roots are not constructible by ruler and compass.